# Every time I git push, I get this /etc/ghrc-secrets: Permission denied message

Tags: git, github, permission-denied, git-push

Every time I git push, I get a cryptic error message.
The weird thing is, the push seems to go through just fine!  Here's the full output:

```
$ git push
/data/github/shell/bin/gh-environment: line 84: /etc/ghrc-secrets: Permission denied
/data/github/shell/bin/gh-environment: line 84: /etc/ghrc-secrets: Permission denied
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 1.02 KiB, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:REDACTED/REDACTED.git
   0f6db16..0321871  master -> master
```

The error messages are happening every time, in every one of my repos on github, all of a sudden.  And yet I check online and all my changes are pushed successfully.

It seems to be something strange when it goes to connect, rather than when it actually pushes data.  Because when I have nothing to push, the error is still there, and always twice:

```
$ git push
/data/github/shell/bin/gh-environment: line 84: /etc/ghrc-secrets: Permission denied
/data/github/shell/bin/gh-environment: line 84: /etc/ghrc-secrets: Permission denied
Everything up-to-date
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

False alarm!  This was a problem on github's end, and it's now been resolved.

Comment: I'm still hitting this today (20 Feb 2013).

Comment: it seems github is having intermittent problems.  on status.github.com it's displaying "Storage Availability - Experiencing Problems"